# Python filling option_buttons with fillpdf in fillable pdf

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

using fillpdf to fill the fields of a fillable pdf. I can't fill the Option_Buttons, no matter which of the values suggested in documentation(https://pypi.org/project/fillpdf/) I'll assign it will throw the following keyerror:

> File "/home/josquin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fillpdf/fillpdfs.py", line 245, in write_fillable_pdf
> raise KeyError(f"{data_dict[key]} Not An Option, Options are {options}")
> KeyError: "Yes Not An Option, Options are ['']"

Does it mean the option buttons are not supported?
here's my code:
from fillpdf import fillpdfs

```
class Scrivischeda:

    def __init__(self, dizscheda):
         self.dizscheda = dizscheda 
         print(self.dizscheda)




          
         sb = {'Text Box 1': self.dizscheda['Num-cartella'], 
               'Text Box 2': self.dizscheda['Data-comp'], 
               'Text Box 3': self.dizscheda['CognomeNome'], 
               'Text Box 4': self.dizscheda['Nazione'], 
               'Text Box 5': self.dizscheda['Nato-a'], 
               'Text Box 6': self.dizscheda['Nato-il'], 
               'Text Box 7': self.dizscheda['Domicilio'], 
               'Text Box 8': self.dizscheda['Telefono'], 
               'Text Box 9': self.dizscheda['Email'], 
               'Text Box 10':self.dizscheda['Tel-amico'], 
               'Text Box 11': self.dizscheda['In-Italia-da'], 
               'Text Box 12':self.dizscheda['Inviato-da'], 
               'Option Button 8': '', 
               'Option Button 9': '', 
               'Text Box 13':self.dizscheda['Ling-madre'], 
               'Option Button 10': '', 
               'Option Button 11': '', 
               'Text Box 14': self.dizscheda['Ling-veicolare'], 
               'Option Button 12': '', 
               'Text Box 15': self.dizscheda['Altro'], 
               'Text Box 18': self.dizscheda['Scolarita-altro'], 
               'Text Box 19': self.dizscheda['Scolarita-anni'], 
               'Check Box 5':'', 
               'Option Button 1': 'Yes' , 
               'Option Button 2': '', 
               'Check Box 6': '', 
               'Check Box 7': '', 
               'Option Button 3': '', 
               'Check Box 8': '', 
               'Option Button 4': '' , 
               'Check Box 9': '', 
               'Text Box 16': self.dizscheda['Num-figli'], 
               'Check Box 10': '', 
               'Check Box 11': '', 
               'Check Box 1': '', 
               'Check Box 2': '', 
               'Check Box 12': '', 
               'Check Box 3': '', 
               'Check Box 4': '', 
               'Check Box 13': '', 
               'Text Box 20':self.dizscheda['Abitazione-altro'], 
               'Option Button 5': '', 
               'Option Button 6': '', 
               'Check Box 15': '', 
               'Check Box 14': '', 
               'Check Box 17': '', 
               'Check Box 16': '', 
               'Option Button 7': '', 
               'Check Box 19': '', 
               'Check Box 18': '', 
               'Text Box 17': self.dizscheda['Lavoro-orig'], 
               'Text Box 21': self.dizscheda['Note'], 
               'Text Box 23': self.dizscheda['Num-cartella'], 
               'Text Box 24':'', 
               'Text Box 22': self.dizscheda['Accolto-da'], 
               'Check Box 2_2': '', 
               'Check Box 1_2': '', 
               'Check Box 3_2': '', 
               'Check Box 6_2': '', 
               'Check Box 7_2': '', 
               'Check Box 5_2': '', 
               'Check Box 4_2': '', 
               'Text Box 1_2': self.dizscheda['CognomeNome'], 
               'Text Box 2_2': self.dizscheda['Nato-a'], 
               'Text Box 3_2': self.dizscheda['Domicilio']}


         fillpdfs.write_fillable_pdf('/home/josquin/ricdoc/schedaform5.pdf', '/home/josquin/ricdoc/schede/scheda-{}.pdf'.format(self.dizscheda['CognomeNome']),sb )
```

Comment: As the error said, *"Yes"* is not an option (I think it is related to "Option Button 1") because the option list in the PDF for that field is a list of single empty string, i.e. `['']`.

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter?

Comment: @BryanOakley nothing really, my bad.